# isAlive problem..Help to understand how it works

Tags: java

I get this error:

```
"non-static method isAlive() cannot be referenced from a static context"
```

what's wrong with this code..please.

I'd like to detect if the thread is alive...
Any help in terms of code will be highly appreciated..thanks
max

> ```
> class RecThread extends Thread {
>
>     public void run() {
>
>         recFile = new File("recorded_track.wav");
>         // Output file type
>         AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = null;
>         fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
>
>         // if rcOn =1 thread is alive 
>         int rcOn;
>
>         try {
>             // starts recording
>             targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
>
>
>             targetDataLine.start();
>
>
>             AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine),
> fileType, recFile);
>
>             if (RecThread.isAlive() == true) {
>             rcOn =1;
>         }
>         else {
>         rcOn =0;
>     }
>
>
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             showException(e);
>         }
>
>         // update actions
>
>         recAction.setEnabled(true);
>         stopRecAction.setEnabled(false);
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Extending Thread is generally not such a good idea, try Runnable instead. And please use boolean variables for rcOn.

Comment: *if (boolean == true)* isn't very nice to read.  People tend to prefer simply:  *if (boolean)*

Answer (score 2):

```
if (RecThread.isAlive() == true) {
```

this line is problematic.  isAlive() is not a static method, which means it can only act on an instance of a Thread.  you are using it in a static context by calling it with a type (RecThread) instead of an object.

Comment: that said, i think changing RecThread to this is analogous to putting a bandaid on a festering boil

Comment: @org.life.java it will always return true in the `run()` method unless you call a dead Thread's run method from another Thread. One more reason to use Runnable instead of Thread. Then you don't get `this.isAlive()`.

Comment: the proble is that I don't know how to check if a thread is running.
My purpose is that I want the user is unable to close the application whenever
RecThread is alive.
I'll probably post another question .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access in a static way   to a method which is not static. I mean, isAlive() method returns if the thread which is running the current instance is not dead.

That's why isAlive() is not static, it is bounded to an instance (to the state of the thread) not to the class     itself.

Answer (score 0):

No meaning in checking isAlive() from within run()..If it is executing code in run() it means it is live
If some other thread has an object of RecThread, then that thread can use recThread.isAlive() to see if its still running